# unable to view welcome page in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.gopal.springmvc</groupId>
<artifactId>springmvctest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springmvctest Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>springmvctest</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application    
  2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
  <web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.gopal.springmvc"/>
   <bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
 </beans>
```

This is my controller:

```
  @Controller
  public class RegistrationLoginController {

  private static final Logger logger =    
  Logger.getLogger(RegistrationLoginController.class);

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome() {
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("getWelcome is executed!");
    }
    System.out.println("Helloooooooo<<<<<");
    //@RequestParam
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginForm() {
    //@RequestParam
    return null;
}
```

}

This is my welcome.jsp file which is available in /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

  </head>
    <body>

     <h2>Login Form</h2>



      </body>
   </html>
```

When I am running this application in tomcat server using eclipse, I am not able to find welcome.jsp page. I can see in console print message and log message which is present in my controller. That means request is passing through welcome() method of RegistrationLoginController. my problem is that I am not able to get welcome.jsp page. Please help me to find the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an error in the IDE? Or is it just ignoring the return value of welcome() completely?

Comment: every things  looks fine...   you need to look in console for any error...  or add more detail here like your console log...

Comment: I am not getting any error in console. My console output is like this:                       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 04, 2018 4:24:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5889 ms
2018-08-04 16:24:43 DEBUG RegistrationLoginController:25 - getWelcome is executed!

Comment: I would suggest that you start using spring-boot. It is exactly the same as spring, but all the configuration is done for you automatically. It's going to save you a lot of trouble in the future

Comment: I would not use web.xml approach and use Java Config using Spring Boot, it would be much easier.

Comment: `@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView passParametersWithModelAndView() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", "hiii");
    return modelAndView;
}` Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return <path_of_jsp> + "/welcome.jsp";
```

To get the path, right click on the file "welcome.jsp" from your IDE and choose Copy Path (*Ctrl+Shift+C* for IntelliJ).

Then paste it to your code like the example above.

your controller method should look something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String welcome() {

  return "C:/WHATEVER_YOUR_PATH_IS/welcome.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Why and how I can do it in controller? I have gone through many spring mvc tutorial. I have followed that only.